# How does the time relationship between a Cookie and FormsAuthenticationTicket really work?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, iis-7, formsauthenticationticket

I'm doing a bit of testing on Cookie/FormsAuthenticationTicket/Session timeouts.  During my testing I found something really interesting.

Create a Session Cookie

`cookie.Expires = DateTime.MinValue;`

Create a FormsAuthenticationTicket with an expiration of 5 minutes

Set Session Timeout in web.config to 3 minutes

Then I created a asp.net button that simply calls `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);` to refresh the page to see if i'm still in the secure section of the page.

If i continuously refresh the page the FormsAuthenticationTicket lasts greater than 5 minutes.

So my questions are:

I'm assuming this is by design but is this true?

Is this because this is a session cookie?

If it is because it's a session cookie, whats the expected behavior of a non-session cookie?

Comment: Take a look at this.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443  Also part of the reason that your authentication is refreshed is because the default value of sliding expiration is true http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.slidingexpiration.aspx

Comment: @TimothyRandall make http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.slidingexpiration.aspx the answer and i'll give ya credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments this is due to the default value of sliding expiration being true:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.formsauthenticationconfiguration.slidingexpiration.aspx

Thanks!